# event bubbling and delegation of chained events

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to resolve the following situation:

I have a link, which has an on click event (it does some ajax manipulation). The click action is a default Rails which will perform a remote action (execute javascript). I want to call this on click event when the li element is clicked with the following html structure:

```
<li>
   <img src="images/img.png" />
   <a href="/remote/path" data-remote="true">Link</a>
</li>
```

The click on li element should trigger on click event on the link and call some other functions (set active class on the li element).

The problem is that:
1. if I bind click event on li and call click event on link, it will cause an endless loop
2. if I put a stopPropagation() on a link, it won't call the original function, which performs a remote request

What would be the most elegant solution to this?

Here's the jcode that I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#some_list a").click(function(e) {
        alert("action on a");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("#some_list li").click(function(e) {
        alert("call some function");
        $(this).find('a').trigger("click");
    });
});
```

This won't cause recursive loop, but it wil prevent the default action that I want to trigger on the link (set by rails or ujs library).

I guess I have to change the order of click actions on a link and stopPropagation() after the last action on the link?

Or maybe there is some better solution with restructuring the HTML and calling the remote function by myself?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can also do window.location = 'anyurl', or ajax.
Try something like this

```
$(function(){
 var myobj = {
 clickedLi: function(){
      alert('clicked on li');
      return this; 
 },
 sendAnchor: function(url){
    alert(url);
    return this;
 }                                   
};

$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
myobj.clickedLi().sendAnchor($(this).find('a').attr('href'));

});
});
```

here is working example
http://jsbin.com/oVAWEdob/2/edit

Comment: So where it says alert(url) just replace with window.location or any ajax call. Let me know if you have any questions.